# Salesforce or Oracle Rightnow?

Tags: community, social-content

Probably this is not the best place for asking this.

We have to analyze / decide which product is the best for managing a Social community.
Different products have been mentioned, like Jive, Dimelo, Salesforce, Oracle Rightnow, etc.
Now there are only 2 candidates (salesforce and Rightnow). I am pretty sure that a comparison between these two products have been already done.

Does anybody know a feature comparison matrix between these two products?
Any comment / recommendation / link will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I also think this is not the best place to ask this.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at the comparison I got [here](http://www.getapp.com/compare/customer-service-software/oracle-rightnow-vs-salesforce) which gives a pretty broad overview.